# How to change the position of the hands of an analog clock for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm working on an analog clock, using this tutorial:
[Make your own analog clock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1703238)

The layout I want to use is a bit different though. I want to make a 4x2 analog clock, with the actual clock on the left, and on the right a small bar with some text. The problem I'm having is that the hands of the clock stay in the middle of the image, instead of on the left. The code in my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/analogClock4x2countdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:dial="@drawable/hand_dial_4x2countdown"
            android:hand_hour="@drawable/hand_hour"
            android:hand_minute="@drawable/hand_minute" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[An example of what it looks like visually](http://i233.photobucket.com/albums/ee286/ringquellecalentil/telefoontje.jpg). This also shows what the problem is.

My question is: how do I position the hands of the clock so that they are in the right spot?

Comment: Please complete that tutorial then come back if you still have a question.

Comment: I have finished the mentioned tutorial and the end result works fine. The problem is that I can't seem to position the hands of the clock in the right plae, as shown in the image I posted.

Comment: The solution I used in the end is making the dial of the clock transparant and putting an image behind it. I then moved the clock with the transparant dial so that it was aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the position and size of the clock by draging the widget on graphic layout on xml only but in relative layout draging according to your wish may not be possible choos one absolute layout as the maun layout